# Excel VLOOKUP function cannot return newline characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Please look at this gif.

[image]

The function call is `=VLOOKUP(A1, A1:B1, 2, FALSE)`.

I want:

```
1. b
2. c
```

but got:

```
1. b2. c
```

the newline character loosed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used the correct formula. However, excel just shows that in one line. click on the cell and do "wrap text". Then it will show them in two lines.[Check this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJa7V.png)

Also check this link where there is a similar issue:
https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/649990-vlookup-preserve-carriage-return-alt-enter.html

Answer (score 2):

I have the french edition but just click on the button surrounded with red, 
you can see it works.

enjoy!!

[image: Excel screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If im understanding it correctly . You should probably put them in separate line. For example you can put 1.b in b1 and 2.c in b2 then try the code.

Comment: `1.b` and `2.c` in the same cell but different line.